# How to make an array of color dots from image array?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I have bunch of color images loaded into a list of numpay.ndarray:

```
for filename in os.listdir(folder):
        img = mpimg.imread(os.path.join(folder, filename))
        if img is not None:
            images.append(img)
```

so their shape is 3024x4032x3  (height, width, color-chanel)

How to make an array of color dots: [['r','g','b'], .... ]
shape must be, i guess like (3, 3024*4032) (where * is multiply)

Comment: Some piece of information is missing, I think. You have a list of hundreds (thousands?) of 12 Megapixel images and you want some dots?

Comment: This question needs much better explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things first:

1. The shape that you are looking for is actually (3024*4032, 3) not the other way. Since you need a list of 3024*4032 items, each item having 3 values of the type [r,g,b].
2. By default, the ndarray that you get while reading an image is of the shape (x,y,3). When you take a close look, its actually a matrix of X and Y, but each element in this matrix is a [r,g,b] list already.
3. The solution you need is simply a reshape -

```
img.reshape((3024*4032,3))
```

Comment: Oh, yes. Thank you for explanation. And  as I find out reshape doesnt save its own work without assigning.